# Can't reach Vagrant box over public network

Tags: vagrant

I want to be able to use computer 1 (iMac) to a view a site on a Vagrant Box (running a LAMP stack in my case) on computer 2 (Macbook) over a Wifi connection (AirPort/Timecapsule), but I just cannot get this working. Both computers are on the same network.

As I understand it, adding the line:

```
config.vm.network "public_network", ip: "192.168.XX.XX"
```

and choosing Wifi (AirPort) from the list that the vagrant reload -commands presents, should make the virtual machine available to computer 1 over the network. Hence hitting `http://192.168.XX.XX/mysite` from computer 2 should present the site.

Trying this however ends with the browser giving me a timeout error. What could be wrong? Everything works just fine while viewing the site on the host machine (computer 2) when running the same line but with `"private_network"` instead.

I'm running vagrant 1.6.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st

Make sure the 2nd virtual interface get an IP address within network. Run `ip addr` inside the VM and see the IP addresses, simply use below in your `Vagrantfile`

```rb
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.network "public_network"
end
```

> NOTE: it is possible that the router work as DHCP server and you'd better use DHCP to set up route/gateway/DNS rather than specifying a static IP and then manually configure DNS, route(gateway).

2nd

Make sure firewall is not blocking access to the IP and port
Run `iptables -L -vn` and see the list